# How do I finalize a class based Saga, so that it is deleted from the SQL database (EF Core)?

Tags: c#, masstransit, ef-core-2.0

I am trying to learn more about Mass Transit as we are thinking about adopting it.  I now have the class based Saga below, which works as expected:

```
public class EchoSaga : ISaga,
        InitiatedBy<TextEntered>,
        Orchestrates<TextEchoStart>,
        Orchestrates<EchoEnd>
    {
        public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }
        public string CurrentState { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TextEntered> context)
        {
            CurrentState = "Entered";
            Text = context.Message.Text;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<TextEchoStart> context)
        {
            CurrentState = "Start";
            Text = context.Message.Text;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public Task Consume(ConsumeContext<EchoEnd> context)
        {
            CurrentState = "End";
            Text = context.Message.Text;
            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }
```

A class based Saga is different to a state machine Saga and is described more in the docs here in the Saga section: http://masstransit-project.com/MassTransit/understand/key-ideas.html.

How do I mark the Saga as finalized after EchoEnd is consumed so it is deleted from the database (I have already setup the repository)? If I was using a state machine Saga, then I could do this:

```
.Finalize()
.SetCompletedWhenFinalized()
```

How do I do this with a class based Saga?

I realise I may be going backwards a bit here, however I am trying to learn how Mass Transit started and where it is now to see if it meets our requirements.  Very pleased with it so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you cast the `ConsumeContext` to `SagaConsumeContext<TSaga, TMessage>`, there is a `SetCompleted` method which signals the saga is complete and can be removed from the repository.

You may need to use `context.GetPayload<SagaConsumeContext<TSaga, TMessage>>()` if casting directly doesn't work (due to proxy use in the pipeline).

Comment: The first paragraph was enough for me.  However, thanks for adding the second paragraph as it works as well - +1 for that.