# When/how is a consumer saga completed?

Tags: c#, masstransit, saga, automatonymous

The MassTransit [documentation on sagas](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html#completed-instance) describes how

> By default, instances are not removed from the saga repository.

It goes on to describe how a saga may be marked for removal from the saga repository.

The documentation for [consumer sagas](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/consumer-saga.html) does not mention completion.

**How is a consumer saga removed from the saga repository in MassTransit?**

Comment: I've found that the question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56526784/3905343). However the other answer was hard to find so I'll leave this question for people who may be using similar search terms.

Comment: You can close it as duplicate and indicate that your problem is solved