# How do Sagas get deleted in MassTransit?

Tags: c#, masstransit

With Sagas in MassTransit, I can add a persistence provider, so that their state is persisted. However, can I somehow remove state for a specific saga again? And if this is done automatically, when is it done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I finalize a class based Saga, so that it is deleted from the SQL database (EF Core)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56516412/how-do-i-finalize-a-class-based-saga-so-that-it-is-deleted-from-the-sql-databas)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Saga is automatically deleted when you complete saga (finalize) and call SetCompletedWhenFinalized();

```
        DuringAny(
            When(OrderCompleted)
                .Finalize());

        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
```

or use custom complete definition

```
        DuringAny(
            When(OrderCompleted)
                .TransitionTo(Completed));

        SetCompleted(async instance => 
        {
            State<TInstance> currentState = await this.GetState(instance);

            return Completed.Equals(currentState);
        });

...

    public State Completed { get; private set; }
```

[More in docs](https://masstransit-project.com/usage/sagas/automatonymous.html#completed-instance)

Comment: Nice - does this apply to Consumer Sagas too?

Comment: Probably yes, but I definitely prefer to use automatonymous.